# Is there a description of variation of (mixed) Hodge Structures in terms of a Deligne operator?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, hodge-theory

A complex Mixed Hodge Structure is given by a complex vector space $V$ together with a descending filtration $W$ and two ascending filtrations $F,\bar{F}$ that satisfy the condition

\begin{equation}
gr_F^pgr_{\bar{F}}^qgr_n^W(V)=0\qquad\text{if }n\neq p+q
\end{equation}

It is a result of Deligne that this is the equivalent to the data of a bigraded vector space $\tilde{V}$, together with an automorphism $\delta$ satisfying

\begin{equation}
(\delta-1)(\tilde{V}^{p,q})\subset\bigoplus_{p'<p,q'<q}\tilde{V}^{p',q'}
\end{equation}

Is there a version of this that carries over to families, i.e. can a variation of Mixed Hodge Structure also be described by something like a (maybe $C^{\infty}$-) bundle with a decomposition into subbundles and a bundle automorphism? If yes, how does Griffiths transversality enter the picture?

Comment: reposted this on MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/224934/is-there-a-description-of-variation-of-mixed-hodge-structures-in-terms-of-a-de